# what is the alternative of java argument: ( Region.Op.REPLACE) in android 9 and higher

Tags: java, android, canvas, java-me, deprecated

The code "Region.Op.REPLACE", at two places in AndroidDisplayGraphics.java throws illegalArgumentException in android 9 and later versions due to policy change.
Here is the complete java code of AndroidDisplayGraphics.java:

```
/**
*  MicroEmulator
*  Copyright (C) 2008 Bartek Teodorczyk <barteo@barteo.net>
*
*  It is licensed under the following two licenses as alternatives:
*    1. GNU Lesser General Public License (the "LGPL") version 2.1 or any newer version
*    2. Apache License (the "AL") Version 2.0
*
*  You may not use this file except in compliance with at least one of
*  the above two licenses.
*
*  You may obtain a copy of the LGPL at
*      http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt
*
*  You may obtain a copy of the AL at
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
*  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
*  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
*  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*  See the LGPL or the AL for the specific language governing permissions and
*  limitations.
*
*  @version $Id: AndroidDisplayGraphics.java 2522 2011-11-28 13:44:59Z barteo@gmail.com $
*/

package org.microemu.android.device;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.Font;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.Sprite;

import org.microemu.log.Logger;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;

public class AndroidDisplayGraphics extends javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics {
    
    public Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
    
    public Paint fillPaint = new Paint();
    
    public AndroidFont androidFont;
    
    private static final DashPathEffect dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 5, 5 }, 0);
    
    private static final Matrix identityMatrix = new Matrix();
    
    private Canvas canvas;
    
    private GraphicsDelegate delegate;

    private Rect clip;
    
    private Font font;
    
    private int strokeStyle = SOLID;
    
    private Rect tmpRect = new Rect();
    
    private Rect tmpRectSecond = new Rect();
    
    private Matrix tmpMatrix = new Matrix();
    
    public AndroidDisplayGraphics() {
        this.delegate = null;
        
        strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        fillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }
    
    public AndroidDisplayGraphics(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        this.canvas.clipRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        this.delegate = null;
        
        strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        fillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        
        reset(this.canvas);
    }
    
    public void reset(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        
        Rect tmp = this.canvas.getClipBounds();
        this.canvas.setMatrix(identityMatrix);
        // setMatrix changes the clipping too
        this.canvas.clipRect(tmp, Region.Op.REPLACE);
        clip = this.canvas.getClipBounds();
        setFont(Font.getDefaultFont());
    }
    
    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }
    
    public void setDelegate(GraphicsDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void clipRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        canvas.clipRect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        clip = canvas.getClipBounds();
        
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.setClip(clip.left, clip.top, clip.right - clip.left, clip.bottom - clip.top);
        }
    }

    public void drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle) {
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, -startAngle, -arcAngle, false, strokePaint);
    }

    public void drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int anchor) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.drawImage(img, x, y, anchor);
        } else {
            int newx = x;
            int newy = y;
    
            if (anchor == 0) {
                anchor = javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.TOP | javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.LEFT;
            }
    
            if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.RIGHT) != 0) {
                newx -= img.getWidth();
            } else if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.HCENTER) != 0) {
                newx -= img.getWidth() / 2;
            }
            if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.BOTTOM) != 0) {
                newy -= img.getHeight();
            } else if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.VCENTER) != 0) {
                newy -= img.getHeight() / 2;
            }
    
            if (img.isMutable()) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidMutableImage) img).getBitmap(), newx, newy, strokePaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImmutableImage) img).getBitmap(), newx, newy, strokePaint);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        } else {
            if (x1 == x2) {
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2 + 1, strokePaint);
            } else if (y1 == y2) {
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 + 1, y2, strokePaint);
            } else { 
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 + 1, y2 + 1, strokePaint);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width, y + height, strokePaint);
        }
    }

    public void drawRoundRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int arcWidth, int arcHeight) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height), (float) arcWidth, (float) arcHeight, strokePaint);
   }

    public void drawString(String str, int x, int y, int anchor) {
        drawSubstring(str, 0, str.length(), x, y, anchor);
    }

    public void drawSubstring(String str, int offset, int len, int x, int y, int anchor) {
        int newx = x;
        int newy = y;

        if (anchor == 0) {
            anchor = javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.TOP | javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.LEFT;
        }
        
        if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.TOP) != 0) {
            newy -= androidFont.metrics.ascent;
        } else if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.BOTTOM) != 0) {
            newy -= androidFont.metrics.descent;
        }
        if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.HCENTER) != 0) {
            newx -= androidFont.paint.measureText(str) / 2;
        } else if ((anchor & javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics.RIGHT) != 0) {
            newx -= androidFont.paint.measureText(str);
        }

        androidFont.paint.setColor(strokePaint.getColor());

        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.drawSubstringDelegate(str, offset, len, newx, newy, anchor);
        } else {    
            canvas.drawText(str, offset, len + offset, newx, newy, androidFont.paint);
        }
    }

    public void fillArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle) {
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, -startAngle, -arcAngle, true, fillPaint);
    }

    public void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width, y + height, fillPaint);
        }
    }

    public void fillRoundRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int arcWidth, int arcHeight) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height), (float) arcWidth, (float) arcHeight, fillPaint);
    }

    public int getClipHeight() {
        return clip.bottom - clip.top;
    }

    public int getClipWidth() {
        return clip.right - clip.left;
    }

    public int getClipX() {
        return clip.left;
    }

    public int getClipY() {
        return clip.top;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return strokePaint.getColor();
    }

    public Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }
    
    public int getStrokeStyle() {
        return strokeStyle;
    }

    public void setClip(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (x == clip.left && x + width == clip.right && y == clip.top && y + height == clip.bottom) {
            return;
        }

        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.setClip(x, y, width, height);
        }

        clip.left = x;
        clip.top = y;
        clip.right = x + width;
        clip.bottom = y + height;
        canvas.clipRect(clip, Region.Op.REPLACE);
    }

    public void setColor(int RGB) {
        strokePaint.setColor(0xff000000 | RGB);
        fillPaint.setColor(0xff000000 | RGB);
    }

    public void setFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
        
        androidFont = AndroidFontManager.getFont(font);

    }
    
    public void setStrokeStyle(int style) {
        if (style != SOLID && style != DOTTED) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        
        this.strokeStyle = style;
        
        if (style == SOLID) {
            strokePaint.setPathEffect(null);
            fillPaint.setPathEffect(null);
        } else { // DOTTED
            strokePaint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
            fillPaint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
        }
    }

    public void translate(int x, int y) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.translate(x, y);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(x, y);
        }
            
        super.translate(x, y);
            
        clip.left -= x;
        clip.right -= x;
        clip.top -= y;
        clip.bottom -= y;
    }

    public void drawRegion(Image src, int x_src, int y_src, int width,
            int height, int transform, int x_dst, int y_dst, int anchor) {
        // may throw NullPointerException, this is ok
        if (x_src + width > src.getWidth() || y_src + height > src.getHeight() || width < 0 || height < 0 || x_src < 0
                || y_src < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Area out of Image");

        // this cannot be done on the same image we are drawing
        // check this if the implementation of getGraphics change so
        // as to return different Graphic Objects on each call to
        // getGraphics
        if (src.isMutable() && src.getGraphics() == this)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Image is source and target");

        Bitmap img;
        if (src.isMutable()) {
            img = ((AndroidMutableImage) src).getBitmap();
        } else {
            img = ((AndroidImmutableImage) src).getBitmap();
        }            

        tmpMatrix.reset();
        int dW = width, dH = height;
        switch (transform) {
        case Sprite.TRANS_NONE: {
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_ROT90: {
            tmpMatrix.preRotate(90);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            dW = height;
            dH = width;
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_ROT180: {
            tmpMatrix.preRotate(180);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_ROT270: {
            tmpMatrix.preRotate(270);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            dW = height;
            dH = width;
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR: {
            tmpMatrix.preScale(-1, 1);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR_ROT90: {
            tmpMatrix.preScale(-1, 1);
            tmpMatrix.preRotate(-90);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            dW = height;
            dH = width;
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR_ROT180: {
            tmpMatrix.preScale(-1, 1);
            tmpMatrix.preRotate(-180);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            break;
        }
        case Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR_ROT270: {
            tmpMatrix.preScale(-1, 1);
            tmpMatrix.preRotate(-270);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, x_src, y_src, width, height, tmpMatrix, true);
            dW = height;
            dH = width;
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad transform");
        }

        // process anchor and correct x and y _dest
        // vertical
        boolean badAnchor = false;

        if (anchor == 0) {
            anchor = TOP | LEFT;
        }

        if ((anchor & 0x7f) != anchor || (anchor & BASELINE) != 0)
            badAnchor = true;

        if ((anchor & TOP) != 0) {
            if ((anchor & (VCENTER | BOTTOM)) != 0)
                badAnchor = true;
        } else if ((anchor & BOTTOM) != 0) {
            if ((anchor & VCENTER) != 0)
                badAnchor = true;
            else {
                y_dst -= dH - 1;
            }
        } else if ((anchor & VCENTER) != 0) {
            y_dst -= (dH - 1) >>> 1;
        } else {
            // no vertical anchor
            badAnchor = true;
        }

        // horizontal
        if ((anchor & LEFT) != 0) {
            if ((anchor & (HCENTER | RIGHT)) != 0)
                badAnchor = true;
        } else if ((anchor & RIGHT) != 0) {
            if ((anchor & HCENTER) != 0)
                badAnchor = true;
            else {
                x_dst -= dW - 1;
            }
        } else if ((anchor & HCENTER) != 0) {
            x_dst -= (dW - 1) >>> 1;
        } else {
            // no horizontal anchor
            badAnchor = true;
        }

        if (badAnchor) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad Anchor");
        }
         
        tmpRect.left = x_src;
        tmpRect.top = y_src;
        tmpRect.right = x_src + width;
        tmpRect.bottom = y_src + height;
        tmpRectSecond.left = x_dst;
        tmpRectSecond.top = y_dst;
        tmpRectSecond.right = x_dst + width;
        tmpRectSecond.bottom = y_dst + height;
        
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.drawRegionDelegate(img, tmpRect, tmpRectSecond);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(img, tmpRect, tmpRectSecond, strokePaint);
        }
    }

    public void drawRGB(int[] rgbData, int offset, int scanlength, int x,
            int y, int width, int height, boolean processAlpha) {
        if (rgbData == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int l = rgbData.length;
        if (width < 0 || height < 0 || offset < 0 || offset >= l || (scanlength < 0 && scanlength * (height - 1) < 0)
                || (scanlength >= 0 && scanlength * (height - 1) + width - 1 >= l)) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        
        // MIDP allows almost any value of scanlength, drawBitmap is more strict with the stride
        if (scanlength == 0) {
            scanlength = width;
        }
        int rows = rgbData.length / scanlength;
        if (rows < height) {
            height = rows;
        }
        
        canvas.drawBitmap(rgbData, offset, scanlength, x, y, width, height, processAlpha, strokePaint);
    }

    public void fillTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.fillTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
        } else {
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(x1, y1);
            path.lineTo(x2, y2);
            path.lineTo(x3, y3);
            path.lineTo(x1, y1);
            canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
        }
    }

    public void copyArea(int x_src, int y_src, int width, int height,
            int x_dest, int y_dest, int anchor) {
        Logger.debug("copyArea");
    }

    public int getDisplayColor(int color) {
        Logger.debug("getDisplayColor");

        return -1;
    }
    
}
```

logcat shows as follows:

```
10-10 19:26:13.970 D/AndroidRuntime(20484): Shutting down VM
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484): Process: org.microemu.android.ketabche.QuranSearch, PID: 20484
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp(Canvas.java:779)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.graphics.Canvas.clipRect(Canvas.java:826)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at org.microemu.android.device.AndroidDisplayGraphics.reset(AndroidDisplayGraphics.java:101)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at org.microemu.android.device.ui.AndroidCanvasUI$CanvasView.onDraw(AndroidCanvasUI.java:225)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20207)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3318)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3122)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2481)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1463)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
10-10 19:26:13.971 E/AndroidRuntime(20484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-10 19:26:13.973 W/s.nexuslaunche( 6826): resources.arsc in APK '/data/app/com.UCMobile.intl-ZgwYkgY4BszTYcMmkf6BuQ==/base.apk' is compressed.
10-10 19:26:13.975 W/ActivityManager( 1206):   Force finishing activity org.microemu.android.ketabche.QuranSearch/org.microemu.android.MicroEmulator
10-10 19:26:13.979 D/        (  800): ipc_resp_thread: opcode: 0x2, payload_size: 4, resp_buf size
```

all experts are requested to help fixing this issue and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add full log, show where the log appear and what is your begin data ?

Comment: When you edit your question, on the right there is help. Also, it's markdown, so if you know how to use markdown it's the same here

Comment: Ok. Why the logs are in upper case ?